# Plotting multiple points on a Google Map using geofield in a View

Tags: google-maps, location, views

I have a content type called Installers that has addressfield and geolocation (et al) attached to it.

Following the instructions found here : https://www.drupal.org/node/1944648 I was able to set up a View Page listing the Installers closest to the location entered on the exposed filter.

I've set up an Attachment to that View Page, set as a Geofield Map, and set to inherit the exposed filter. However it displays nothing (just the default location), and certainly doesn't appear to update the map depending on the results of the Page. 
Have I missed a step or is there more to plotting multiple points on a Geofield Map?

Any and all assistance given is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not that anyone replied to this, but I found a rather great solution. For those interested, I used this little gem : https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc